# I can't start the project as it shows error while using the command 'npm start'

Tags: reactjs

Below is the issue I am dealing with while I am starting the project with the command line 'npm start'

> There might be a problem with the project dependency tree. It is
>   likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix
>   locally.
>
> The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a
>   dependency:
>
> "webpack": "4.28.3"
>
> Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it
>   automatically. However, a different version of webpack was detected
>   higher up in the tree:
>
> /Users/sattys/node_modules/webpack (version: 4.29.0)
>
> Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause
>   hard-to-debug issues.
>
> If you would prefer to ignore this check, add
>   SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project. That will
>   permanently disable this message but you might encounter other issues.
>
> To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact
>   order:
>
> 1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
> 2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
> 3. Remove "webpack" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
> 4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.
>
> In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem. If this has
>   not helped, there are a few other things you can try:
>
> 5. If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead.
>       This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.
> 6. Check if /Users/sattys/node_modules/webpack is outside your project directory.
>       For example, you might have accidentally installed something in your home folder.
> 7. Try running npm ls webpack in your project folder.
>       This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected react-scripts) installed webpack.
>
> If nothing else helps, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file
>   in your project. That would permanently disable this preflight check
>   in case you want to proceed anyway.

P.S. We know this message is long but please read the steps above :-) We hope you find them helpful!

> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! errno 1
>
> npm ERR! jvm-configuration@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
>
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Failed at the jvm-configuration@0.1.0 start script.
>
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely
>   additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR!
>   /Users/sattys/.npm/_logs/2019-04-04T12_30_29_925Z-debug.log

Comment: So what is your question exactly? you have done those steps and it does not work yet ?

Comment: Usually this happens when you accidentaly installed a module in your home dir. Try *rm -rf ~/node_modules*

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the suggestion is the error message?

**First Try:**
To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact order:

1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
3. Remove "webpack" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.

**If that doesn't work try:**

If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead. This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.

Check if /Users/sattys/node_modules/webpack is outside your project directory. For example, you might have accidentally installed something in your home folder.

Try running npm ls webpack in your project folder. This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected react-scripts) installed webpack.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install terser@3.14
```

try installing this library,hope it should work

1)Ensure that you are running the same version of Node as the other system where it was seen running perfectly. You can test this by entering the following on your terminal and the terminal it was working on: node -v. If they're different, look to upgrade (or indeed downgrade) your installation.

2)Delete the node_modules and package-lock.json directory from the project root on your current computer, then run an npm install to ensure that the binaries that were compiled are compatible with your operating system.

Comment: Should I install this library globally or in the project folder?? Not only this I am facing this problem on already finished projects.

Comment: project folder itself